# Fontawesome icon width issue

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Have been trying to use fontawesome star icons to create a star rating.

https://codepen.io/ankitkhedekar/pen/gOgqpbv

There are 2 variations of star icons used here `fa-star` and `fa-star-half`. The full star icon is rendered as `36px x 32px` dimensions. The half star icon is rendered as `36px x 32px` as well. I would like the `fa-star-half` to be rendered as `18px x 32px`, which would make the hovering work in better way in example.

Any explanation of the problem better would be helpful

Comment: This could help: https://codepen.io/anefzaoui/pen/NWPZzMa

Comment: @prettyInPink in that code pen as well, the half star's width is half of the full star whereas in my code you can see it is full width for both. So wanted to understand how and why

Comment: I have the same issue, my guess is they changed how it works with the newest version of font awesome. Did you ever find a solution that you can remember @AnkitKhedekar